# Illegal input detected on my modeling on Scilab

Tags: modeling, ode, scilab

I've been trying to run this on Scilab, but I can't get it to work.

```
global ke Yxs Va Kg A D cx cxa cxamax fbc Kp Yps Ypx umax rho V mg mga mbc nxa

    ke=0.003/(10^9);
    Yxs=45*10^9;
    Va=0.005;
    Kg=0.04;
    A=0.004657;
    D=4.5*10^(-10);
    cx=10^9;
    cxa=10^9;
    cxamax=1163*10^9;
    fbc=0.01;
    Kp=0.01;
    Yps=0.9;
    Ypx=0.01125;
    umax=1.6;
    rho=1030;
    V=0.2;

function ydot=g(t,y)
    ydot=zeros(y);        
    ydot(1)=((umax*((y(3)/Va)/((y(3)/Va)+Kg)))-ke*Yxs)*y(1);
    ydot(2)=-(D*A*(((y(2)/V)-(y(3)/Va))/((y(4)/(rho*fbc))/A)));
    ydot(3)=(D*A*(((y(2)/V)-(y(3)/Va))/((y(4)/(rho*fbc))/A)))-((umax*((y(3)/Va)/((y(3)/Va)+Kg)))/Yxs+(Ypx*(umax*((y(3)/Va)/((y(3)/Va)+Kg)))*(y(3)/Va)/(cga+Kp))/Yps)*y(1);
    ydot(4)=(Ypx*(umax*((y(3)/Va)/((y(3)/Va)+Kg)))*(y(3)/Va)/(cga+Kp))*y(1);
endfunction

t0=0;
t=0:1:50;
y0=ones(0,4,4,0);
y=ode(y0,t0,t,g);
```

This is what the console returns when I run it.

```
lsoda--  neq (=i1) .lt. 1     
      where i1 is :          0                                                   
Illegal input detected (see printed message).
at line    52 of executed file C:\Users\pandrade\Documents\Pessoal\Ufla\modelagem artigo.sce

ode: lsoda exit with state -3.
```

Line 52 is the last line of the code, where the ode command is. Does anyone know what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2):

Your intialization of `y0` is incorrect. Maybe you meant:

```
y0=[0;4;4;0]
```

or

```
y0=ones(4,1)
```

In any case `y0` should be a column vector of 4 elements. Moreover you probably misspelled `cga` instead of `cxa` in the code of `g(t,y)`.

Remember to always test that your right hand side function (here `g`) works outside the context of the ode call, by typing something like

```
g(0,y0)
```

on the Scilab command line.